# CSS - Scale font size smooth with body width without javascript

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-size

is it possible to scale the font size smoothly with the width of the body or the parent element ? I´m looking for a solution without javascript. Is it possible to point `rem` to a width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are the 'vh' and 'vw' units. These units related to viewport height and width. http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

Comment: so this would require a modern browser, is there something with more borwser support ?

Comment: you can check browser support with this site: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh this seem relatively well-supported.  You could also use the CSS calc function